# How To Post HTML Via URL

Tags: php, html, url

Is it possible to send html code via a url and display the parameter containing the html code as HTML where the parameter is received?

I.E. `<a href='./displayHtml.php?description=<strong>Title</strong><table>...</table>'>Send Html</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing (by default — XSS filters might not like it) stopping you including characters that have special meaning inside a URL. However:

- You can't make a POST request with a link, the data will appear (in PHP) in `$_GET`
- You should urlencode data before putting it in a URL
- You should HTML encode data before putting it in HTML

Such:

```
<?php
    $description = htmlspecialchars(
        urlencode(
            "<strong>Title</strong>etc etc"
        )
    );
?>
<a href="./displayHtml.php?description=<?=$description?>">
```

Make sure you implement suitable defences against XSS attacks before injecting user input (e.g. anything you read from `$_GET`) into HTML documents though.

Answer (score 1):

Well - you could do this - but it will be very very dangerous

**displayHtml.php**

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

As @Quentin pointed out - there are all sort of XSS/security issues.

edit: this might be *slightly* more secure:

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```